# Having problem getting getDiscount() from the parameter (JAVA)

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor, getter-setter

I want to get **discount** from the **getter in the employee class which extends person class**. The discount varies upon hourlyWorked. I have set up parameters.
I can get the discount when i use setMethods. e.g if i use

```
e.setHourlyWorked(56);
System.out.println(e.getHourlyWorked());
System.out.println(e.getDiscount());
```

I get the result as expected.

But i cant get `e.getDiscount());` from the parameter itself i.e

```
    Employee e= new Employee(23, 22,"Nab","Kar","000");
    System.out.println(e.getHourlyWorked());
    System.out.println(e.getDiscount());
```

I get 0 as discount.

Person class

```
    public  class Person {
    //private fields
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int discount;

    public Person(){
    //Default Constructors
    firstName="John";
    surname="SMITH";
    phoneNumber="0000";


    }//constructors with all the inputs 
    public Person(String fn, String sn, String pn){

        firstName=fn;
        surname=sn;
        phoneNumber=pn;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String fn) {
        firstName=fn;
    }


    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String sn) {
        surname = sn;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String pn) {
        phoneNumber = pn;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getFirstName()+" "+getSurname()+" "+getPhoneNumber();
    }
```

Employee class

```
    package lollyShopSystem;

    public class Employee extends Person {
    private double hourlyWorked;
    private double wage;
    private int dis;

    public Employee(){
    //Default Constructors
    hourlyWorked=30;
    wage=34;

    }
    public Employee(double hourlyWorked, double wage, String fn, String sn, String pn) {
        super(fn, sn, pn);
        this.hourlyWorked = hourlyWorked;
        this.wage = wage;        
    }

    public double getHourlyWorked() {
        return this.hourlyWorked;

    }

    public void setHourlyWorked(double hourlyWorked) {
        this.hourlyWorked = hourlyWorked;

        if (this.hourlyWorked<=20){
            this.dis=5;
    }
        else if (this.hourlyWorked>20 && this.hourlyWorked<=30){
            this.dis=10;
    }
        else {
            this.dis=15;
        }

    }

    public double getWage() {
        return this.wage;
    }

    public void setWage(double wage) {
        this.wage = wage;


    }


public int getDiscount(){
    return this.dis;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `hourlyWorked` using the constructor does not change the discount. You can replace the assignment of the field with the `setHourlyWorked` function instead.

```java
public Employee(double hourlyWorked, double wage, String fn, String sn, String pn) {
    super(fn, sn, pn);
    setHourlyWorked(hourlyWorked);
    this.wage = wage;        
}
```

Comment: what would i have to do if i had to use if statement of discount under `setDiscount()` ?

Comment: @user13558639 If I understood your program, you do not need to have an `if` statement in that function. Use the same technique as the `setWage` function.

Comment: Alternatively, you can move the `if` statement from the `setHourlyWorked` to the `getDiscount` function. When you want to get the discount, the program recalculates the discount before it is displayed. Doing so, you can create an `Employee` instance and right below it call `getDiscount` and the correct value will be shown.